# Integrating Factors - definite with Indefinite integrals

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am self-learning ODEs through https://www.simiode.org/resources/3732/download/Granero-Belinchon-CourseDEAndApplications.pdf?451f56d1cb99f142dee7c2d16251bfcb=1.

Consider $P'(t)=-\alpha P(t)+f(t), P(0)=P_{0}\in \mathbb{R}$
Clearly, then $\frac{d}{dt}[e^{\int_{0}^{t}\alpha (s) ds}P(t)] = e^{\int_{0}^{t}\alpha (s)ds}f(t)$. However, their next step was to say that this is iff
$[e^{\int_{0}^{t}\alpha (s) ds}P(t)] = \int_{0}^{t}e^{\int_{0}^{u}\alpha (s)ds}f(u)du+C$ as if the LHS was integrated as an indefinite integral and the RHS as a definite integral. Is this generally possible? If so, how?

Comment: If you like you can add constants $C_1$ to the left and $C_2$ to the right, but you can bring $C_1$ over to make it $C_2-C_1$ on the right. That is the same as just calling it $C$ on the right.

Comment: @Michael but is it possible to integrate one side under an indefinite integral whilst the other is definite?

Comment: You seemed to have changed the question after my comment. As I recall you had  a $+C$ somewhere...?

Comment: @Michael My bad, there should be a $+C$ on the RHS as I just added

Comment: In that case my first comment applies. It looks like $C=P(0)$.

Comment: @Michael Oh I see: because $e^{\int_{0}^{0}\alpha (s) ds}P(0)=P(0)$ is just being added onto the other side and combined with its constant.